# Can't export features from PostGIS table into ESRI FGDB when text fields contain more than 255 characters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, export, file-geodatabase, arcgis-10.4

I am loading the PostGIS table in ArcMap 10.4.1 using a database connection.  Then I export the loaded layer (Right click, Data, Export Data...) into a newly created File Geodatabase. The procedure is working, there are only a few of the features that are not exported.

Then I tried with QGIS 2.18.11 (Right click, Save, File GDB). The same happens. The same features are not exported to the FGDB.

I looked into the PostGIS table and the failing features all have something in common: they all have one or more text fields wider than 255 characters.

Those same fields in the destination FGDB have a limit of 255 characters.

Is there a way to make the text fields adjust automatically (and larger than 255 chars) to the size of the field in the table being imported?

It is possible to create text fields as wide as 2 147 483 647 characters according to the ESRI docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try right clicking on the File Geodatabase and importing features, instead of right clicking the layer and exporting. That way you should have the option in field mapping to alter text field length

Comment: I would have spent half an hour on the phone with ESRI trying to explain my problem and answering questions to finally being called back the next day telling me that the problem is with my non-ESRI product ;) Community-driven projects are so much better!

Comment: I've not encountered this problem exporting from PostGIS, it could be that there is an intermediate shapefile created which would have a maximum field length of 255. I use Copy_management or CopyFeatures_management to extract the data and if the database is being surly export to XML workspace document (no features), import XML workspace for the new schema in the GDB and load features using the simple data loader or via Append_management, this method gives a chance to edit the XML document before creating the schema.