# "Save As" truncating string fields to 255 characters

Tags: qgis, postgis, ogr, file-geodatabase

I'm trying to convert a postgis table to an ESRI FileGeodatabase with a nightly build of QGIS, using `Save As` which utilises OGR.

One of the fields is a text field with > 255 characters. I have noticed that the field was truncated to 255 characters and then QGIS did not export the records which had more than 255 characters in the field. I then found [this](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/688e9646556d9280f8c8b9286b689bbd22bc99db/src/providers/ogr/qgsogrprovider.cpp#L124) part of the QGIS code which seems to truncate String fields to 255 characters.

I understand that this has always been a limitation for Shapefiles, but it is not for file geodatabases, so it seems bizarre to truncate all text even when the provider supports it. Or is there some other limitation I should be aware of?Maybe should go on QGIS-dev but thought I would get folks' view here first.

Comment: This is definitely something to discuss on the qgis-dev mailinglist (or if you feel confident, even propose a change on this line as pull request on github).

Comment: Technically, the dBase-III limit is 254.

Comment: I had always assumed all the shapefile limitations were ported forward to the FileGeoDatabase spec but as it is a closed format it's hard to say.

Comment: Related: [Can't export features from PostGIS table into ESRI FGDB when text fields contain more than 255 characters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261839/cant-export-features-from-postgis-table-into-esri-fgdb-when-text-fields-contain?rq=1)

Comment: @IanTurton If you look at the published API, it's obvious that file geodatabase does not, did not, and never had any of the baggage of shapefiles. I fear your assumption falls under the famous caveat in that regard.

Comment: Hi ! Did you manage to solve this ? :)